# enable to get cell header name when clicking on it's particuler column along with colspan property

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here am trying to get particuler cells header name when clicking on it's any column cell,here some of cells have colspan property and some of them are not have it,when i have colspan property then am able to get the all header cells name which covered by colspan,but when i have some cells who has colspan  and some of them are not in single row then am enable to get the proper cell header name of those cells who come  after colspan in table 
My HTML is as bellow

```
<table id="example">
<tr>
<th>Rows</th>
<th>cell1</th>
<th>cell2</th>
<th>cell3</th>
<th>cell4</th>
<th>cell5</th>
<th>cell6</th>
<th>cell7</th>
<th>cell8</th>
<th>cell9</th>
<th>10</th></tr>
<tr>
<td  id="1_3">
<a >R1</a>
</td>
<td class="alertShow" id="1_0"></td>
<td class="displaydata">
<span id="id_1_1" class="booked" draggable="true"></span>
</td>
<td class="alertShow" id="1_2"></td>
<td class="displaymultipledata" colspan="3">
<span id="id_1_3" class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
</td>
<td class="alertShow" id="1_6">
</td><td class="alertShow" id="1_7"></td>
<td class="alertShow" id="1_8"></td>
<td class="alertShow" id="1_9"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My Jquery code to read cells header name

```
$('#example').on('click', '.alertShow', function () {
        $('#example thead tr').eq($(this).addClass("background"));
        var rowheader = $('#example thead tr th').eq($(this).index()).html().trim();
}
```

output is as like
[image]

Comment: So if a cell spans three columns, then you want to get _three_ header names back? With cells spanning multiple columns, you can not simply use the index any more; you would need to add up the colspan values of all the previous cells in the row first.

Comment: actuly am done with cells headers who has a colspan property ,the issue is when i have a cells after colspan and when am clicking on them then am not able to gete excat cell header name

Comment: As I said, you can not work with the cell index any more then, but you have to _calculate_ how many columns the previous rows have spanned.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: You go through the cells, and get the content of their colspan attribute (if empty, use 1 instead) - and then you sum them up …

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to calculate header td index based on the td's that have a colspan property and have a index less than the current clicked td. Then simply add sum of all colspan value to index and then use it to get Proper header index.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#example').on('click', '.alertShow', function() {
    $('#example  tr').eq($(this).addClass("background"));

    tdIdx = $(this).index();
    alltd = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:lt(" + tdIdx + ")").filter('td[colspan]');

    colspanTotal = 0;
    $.each(alltd, function(index, td) {
      colspanTotal += parseInt($(td).attr('colspan'));

    });
    if (colspanTotal > 0) {
      colspanTotal = colspanTotal - 1;
    }
    tdIdx = tdIdx + colspanTotal;
    var rowheader = $('#example tr th').eq(tdIdx).html().trim();
    console.log(rowheader);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="example" border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Rows</th>
    <th>cell1</th>
    <th>cell2</th>
    <th>cell3</th>
    <th>cell4</th>
    <th>cell5</th>
    <th>cell6</th>
    <th>cell7</th>
    <th>cell8</th>
    <th>cell9</th>
    <th>10</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="1_3">
      <a>R1</a>
    </td>
    <td class="alertShow" id="1_0">click me</td>
    <td class="displaydata">
      <span id="id_1_1" class="booked" draggable="true"></span>
    </td>
    <td class="alertShow" id="1_2"></td>
    <td class="displaymultipledata" colspan="3">
      <span id="id_1_3" class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
    </td>
    <td class="alertShow" id="1_6">
    </td>
    <td class="alertShow" id="1_7"></td>
    <td class="alertShow" id="1_8"></td>
    <td class="alertShow" id="1_9"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

resolved issue

```
var Headers = ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3", "cell4", "cell5", "cell6", "cell7", "cell8", "cell9", "cell10"];
        var colId = 0;
        var colspan = 0
        colId = this.id;
        colspan = this.colSpan;
        if (colspan === 1) {
            var rowheader = Headers[colId];
        }
```

here i have seted Id to a each cell by applying looping and using this ID to find specific header cell from array